# Contentful content-management (node lib) : entry won't update

Tags: react-native, contentful

Title says all. I think I've tried all possible combinations but none of them seem to work.

What am I doing wrong ?

First :

```
client.getSpace('<SPACEID>')
.then((space) => {
         space.updateEntry({
         "sys": {
         id: "<ENTRYID>",
         version:45
          },
         "fields": {
         "job": {
           "fr-FR": "blablabla"
            }
         }
     })
})
```

=> Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: space.updateEntry is not a function

Second :

```
client.getSpace('<SPACEID>')
        .then((space) => {
          space.getEntry(<ENTRYID>)
            .then((entry) => {
                var ver = entry.sys.version
                var id = entry.sys.id
                entry = {
                    "sys":{
                        id: id,
                        version:ver
                    },
                    "fields": {
                        "job": {
                            "fr-FR": "blablabla"
                        }
                    }
                }
                entry.update()
            })
        })
```

=> got entry.update() is not a function

Third :

```
.then((space) => {
  space.getEntry(entryId)
    .then((entry) => {
        entry.fields.job = {"fr-FR": "blabla"}
        entry.update()
    })
})
```

=> got Exception '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb0000000000002d3'

Fourth :

```
entry.fields.job['fr-FR'] = 'blabla'
```

=> same exception

```
ExceptionsManager.js:78 Exception '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000013' was thrown while invoking sendRequest on target RCTNetworking with params (
        {
        data =         {
            string = "{\"fields\":{\"fireid\":{\"fr-FR\":\"bla\"},\"commission\":{\"fr-FR\":\"bla\"},\"dep\":{\"fr-FR\":\"bla\"},\"desc\":{\"fr-FR\":\"bla\"},\"email\":{\"fr-FR\":\"thp@ggg.com\"},\"firstname\":{\"fr-FR\":\"firstname\"},\"job\":{\"fr-FR\":\"blabla\"},\"name\":{\"fr-FR\":\"name\"},\"tel\":{\"fr-FR\":\"0675234573\"},\"type\":{\"fr-FR\":\"Collaborateur\"}}}";
            trackingName = unknown;
        };
        headers =         {
            accept = "application/json, text/plain, */*";
            authorization = "Bearer TOKEN";
            "content-type" = "application/vnd.contentful.management.v1+json";
            "x-contentful-user-agent" = "contentful-management.js/1.3.1";
            "x-contentful-version" = 1;
        };
        incrementalUpdates = 0;
        method = PUT;
        responseType = text;
        timeout = 0;
        url = "https://api.contentful.com:443/spaces/<SPACEID>/entries/<ENTRYID>";
    },
    139
)
```

Answer (score 0):

to update an entry you can do the following : 
First, you need the entry object either, you create it or get and entry by id :

```
// You can get an Entry object by
// 1. Creating one
var myEntry
space.createEntry({}).then((entry) => {myEntry = entry})

// 2. Get an existing one
space.getEntry('ENTRY_ID').then((entry) => {myEntry = entry})

// to Update an entry you can do the following
entry.fields.name['en-US'] = 'Blog Post'
entry.update()
.then(entry => console.log(entry.fields.name['en-US']))
```

again it depends on the fields of your entry, you might not need to do `[en-US]` if you don't have localized content

Comment: Thanks a lot for your rapid answer, much appreciated. I'd live in a much better worlde if this worked but I really think it doesn't. I can easily create an entry but : 

1/ if I dont do "job:{"fr-FR":"blabla}", API says it needs an object and will reject a string. 

2/ if I try to do anything with the entry created (even entry.publish() ) it will throw an exception Exception '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000013' was thrown while invoking sendRequest on target RCTNetworking

3/ When entry is saved, it is not published (no required field unmet)

Comment: @ThomasPoirier the error is kinda weird and i don't think it is related to the sdk, are you using a network through a proxy or something? What is your actual setup ?

Comment: Set-up is react-native V0.33. The code is : 
  client.getSpace('SPACEID')
  .then(space => {
   space.getEntry(entryId)
   .then(entry => {
    entry.fields.job['fr-FR'] = 'working waouh'
    entry.update()
    .then(entry => console.log(entry.fields.job['fr-FR']))
   })
  })

Comment: Can you console.log the entry object and see if you actually have that field

Comment: Yes console.log gives me the correct value. Code is :   client.getSpace('SPACEID')
  .then(space => {
   space.getEntry(entryId)
   .then(entry => {
    console.log(entry.fields.job['fr-FR'])

Comment: What is you node version? What version of the sdk you are using ?

Comment: Node is 6.2.2 and contenful-management is 1.3.1. Even more strange, I can do entry.unpublish() but not entry.publish(). This could be a work around : 1- Publish the new entry then 2- Unpublish the former one. But well...

Comment: Hmm is job a linked entry or just a normal string field ?

Comment: It's a normal basic string.

Comment: I think this is an issue related to React native, or maybe axios is doing something that React native does not like. can you try this in a normal node app ?

Comment: It works like a charm in a node-react webapp. Changes are still not automatically published though, but .then(entry => entry.publish()) works so everything is fine.

Comment: Yeah that confirms my theory, could be react native related problem